# How can I install GRUB to a different folder than /EFI/ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, grub2

How can I invoke `grub-install` from Ubuntu in a way that it installs its files to a custom directory and **not**, for example, to `/EFI/ubuntu`? Every method I try ends up (still) putting some `.efi` and `.cfg` files into the `/EFI/ubuntu` folder. I want to redirect this folder somewhere else (properly).

Comment: Just curious why you want to do this. And doesn't the location need to be a standard place for the EFI firmware to be able to find it?

Comment: @FaheemMitha: Because I'm trying to install it on a drive intended to boot an OS that isn't the one I'm installing from (aka not Ubuntu), or even on the computer I'm booting from. I don't need advice here though; I know what I'm doing and it's not the usual setup. I'm trying to figure out how to accomplish this exact task.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the explanation. But I still think more context is necessary. And I suggest you put it in the question. I'm tempted to suggest that you just copy the directory to the correct place, But I suppose that wouldn't work, because it wouldn't look for the right boot partition or something.

Answer (score 5):

On all machines that have an UEFI based BIOS, the boot loader HAS to be installed on a separate EFI partition which gets mounted on `/boot/efi` and this is the default location where all operating systems store their **own** boot loader. If you try to change it, the operating system simply won't boot.

Example (on a fedora operating system the boot loader gets installed to the folder `/EFI/fedora`) :

```
$ sudo ls -l /boot/efi
total 4
drwx------. 4 root root 4096  6. Apr 12:51 EFI
$ sudo ls -l /boot/efi/EFI
total 8
drwx------. 2 root root 4096  6. Apr 13:14 BOOT
drwx------. 4 root root 4096 30. Jun 09:02 fedora
$ sudo ls -l /boot/efi/EFI/fedora
total 5820
-rwx------. 1 root root     104 15. Aug 2016  BOOT.CSV
drwx------. 2 root root    4096  6. Apr 13:14 fonts
drwx------. 2 root root    4096 28. Sep 2016  fw
-rwx------. 1 root root   70864 28. Sep 2016  fwupx64.efi
-rwx------. 1 root root  997192  8. Dez 2016  gcdx64.efi
-rwx------. 1 root root    5901 30. Jun 09:02 grub.cfg
-rwx------. 1 root root    1024 30. Jun 09:02 grubenv
-rwx------. 1 root root  997192  8. Dez 2016  grubx64.efi
-rwx------. 1 root root 1276192 15. Aug 2016  MokManager.efi
-rwx------. 1 root root 1293304 15. Aug 2016  shim.efi
-rwx------. 1 root root 1287000 15. Aug 2016  shim-fedora.efi
```

When you install Ubuntu, the boot loader that boots it, HAS to be installed to the sub folder *ubuntu*. The installer creates this folder and installs the boot loaders there automatically - do not modify it !

**Additional information addressing your comment : What if I want to install a GRUB boot manager for a Fedora installation from inside an Ubuntu installation? How can I do this?**

You cannot install the GRUB boot loader from one system to another system and as I said, every operating system installs its own boot manager to an own sub folder. After updating GRUB boot configuration, all installed systems are detected and can be booted from every installed loader.

**More information about how to manage boot loaders when different systems are in use :**

You can choose which boot loader shall be the default boot loader with the `efibootmgr` tool.

```
$ sudo efibootmgr
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0001
Boot0000* fedora
Boot0001* UEFI OS
```

In this example the boot loader from fedora is set to be the default loader ... if you install ubuntu additionally, a new entry `Boot0002* ubuntu` appears and if you want to use that one, execute : `sudo efibootmgr -o 0002,0000,0001`

Comment: -1 Uhm, thanks, but I *don't care* if the OS won't boot. I never even said I'm trying to boot the same OS I'm installing from (I'm not). The reason I want to do this is not relevant here... please trust me that I know what I'm doing and just answer the question. In your own example, the folder is named `fedora`. So the question is if I'm installing from Ubuntu, how can I make it install to a directory called (say) `fedora`? That's all. I'm not seeking advice on anything.

Comment: Another way to rephrase my question is, "What if I want to install a GRUB boot manager for a Fedora installation from inside an Ubuntu installation? How can I do this?" If you're actually saying it's outright *impossible* to do such a thing, please clarify this and I'll accept your answer.

Comment: This is the tool to manipulate: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/efibootmgr.8.html It does not allow a rename, only to delete + recreate with a new label.

Comment: @cl-netbox: Can you edit this into your answer? As it currently stands, it doesn't answer my question... all it says is *"when you install Ubuntu..."* which doesn't make sense because I'm *not* installing Ubuntu.

Comment: +1 for you, however, I'm finding it a little hard to swallow. :-) So you're saying if I have 2 Ubuntu installations and 2 Fedora installations, there will be potentially 2 folders (or perhaps 4) owned by different OSes, and *each* will be capable of booting 4 systems (because GRUB scans for bootable systems automatically when its config file is generated)? That seems a little absurd, doesn't it?

Comment: @cl-netbox: I'm not sure if I'm confused, or if it's you who is confused :) you're starting to talk about the firmware boot setup which I couldn't care less about. Ignore the firmware completely. I don't have any questions about it and it only makes your answer more confusing. I'm simply asking about how many copies of GRUB there are, and how many systems each one would boot. My understanding is if I had 2 Ubuntus and 2 Fedoras, I would have 2 GRUB folders (one for Ubuntus, one for Fedoras) and they would manage 1 shared copy of `\boot\grub\grub.cfg` for all 4 installations. Is that correct?

Comment: @cl-netbox: And if that's correct, I guess the part that I don't get is why it makes sense ot have 2 copies of GRUB binaries for 4 systems (managing the 1 global config). Wouldn't it make sense for there to be either 1 shared binary, or 4 separate binaries? After all, there's nothing more in common between 2 separate Ubuntu installations than between an Ubuntu and a Fedora installation...

Comment: @Mehrdad No, you have only one folder for each system ... the latest installed overwrites the older one - means when you first install ubuntu 16.04, it installs GRUB (version 16.04) to the ubuntu folder and when you install ubuntu 17.04 additionally, it overwrites the files in the ubuntu folder with GRUB (17.04 version). So, on a setup with 2 fedoras and 2 ubuntus you have 1 folder fedora and 1 folder ubuntu. When you run `sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg` on fedora or `sudo update-grub` on ubuntu, all 4 operating systems are detected and shown in their own GRUB menu(s). :)

Comment: @cl-netbox: So you're saying I would see 2 Ubuntus on the Ubuntu menu, and 2 Fedoras on the Fedora menu? But I would **not** see 2 Fedoras on the Ubuntu menu or vice versa?

Comment: @Mehrdad You see 2 fedoras and 2 ubuntus on both GRUB menus after you updated the boot config. :)

Comment: @cl-netbox: Okay, so that's the same thing I was saying initially. So I'm saying, what's the point of this? Wouldn't it make sense to have just 1 GRUB showing all 4 installations?

Comment: @cl-netbox: You're saying there's no way *at all* to install a separate copy of GRUB that is standalone? Every copy of GRUB *has* to be tied to an OS? This is weird because neither rEFInd nor BootMgr behave this way, so it's not like this is inherent to UEFI... it seems to be a GRUB thing?

Comment: @Mehrdad Yes, every copy of GRUB has to be tied to an OS, because different systems ship with different (and sometimes modified) versions of GRUB. So, all I can say is that EFI based machines are designed to do it the way I explained. All systems have an own folder where all boot files (not only the GRUB files) are getting stored and the very same is valid for all other operating systems like the Windows OS for example.

Comment: I would like to just point out that the UEFI specification says nothing about what goes into which folder on the EFI System Partition. The spec says the ESP must be a FAT formatted partition with a fixed UUID, and the firmware loads and starts one EFI binary based on variables in NVRAM. This program can be a boot loader or a boot manager (rEFInd, systemd-boot), which takes control and starts other EFI programs or boots the operating system. On my Arch Linux machine I use systemd-boot and the kernel file is in the root directory of the ESP. Zero copies of GRUB involved :)

Answer (score 1):

```
grub-install --bootloader-id=customfoldername # <-- this is what you want
```

it didn't work for me at first, but then I found [this answer in Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1217666/158442):

> After running grub-install with `--bootloader-id`, run `grub-install` without any arguments. It will create an ubuntu entry. Delete it if you want to, but now your id is going to work "magically". Very annoying, seems to be an old bug.